# How to add a button which scroll along with the user scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add a custom button on my website which scrolls along when user scrolls and I want to keep it at the right most and in the centre.
A one good example of what I want can be seen here at http://www.addthis.com/.
Like the bar there which scrolls down along with user scrolling.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Just simple. Give `position:fixed;` to button.

```css
.main{
    height:1400px;
}
.btnFixed{
    position:fixed;
    top:200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <button class="btnFixed">Button</button>
    
</div>
```

Check [Fiddle Here.](http://jsfiddle.net/v825fh4e/)

Comment: Hi ketan thanks it works but I am a newbie in CSS so can you please tell me how to move it on right?
I have tried float:right but it is not working